# Suggest some projects on parallel computing or HPC

Tags: python, parallel-processing, hpc

I am in need of doing some projects on parallel computing or HPC , can any one suggest me good projects on that , I prefer to use Python as the programming language, can I use it for these also? Please help me in this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python and High Performance Computing? I would use it only as front-end language for managing and monitoring the system... The actual computations should be done in a more machine-friendly language if performance is what you are seeking.

About problems that are fit to be solved in parallel, as always, those composed of independent tasks, like:

- Raytracing
- Genetic algorithms
- Matrix algebra

I'll try to expand the answer in response to your comment:

About SciPy et al. they are really, really great. I've used them a lot and the performance is not bad at all, but the problem is that you must stick to the operations provided by the library (that are written in highly optimized C and compiled to native code), or the performance will drop to Python levels.

So the point is that you will need to think in matrix operations (for example: a weighted sum is a scalar product of two vectors) all the time, and if you need something more specific... Well, you can always write your function in C++ or Fortran with Weaver or in C and make a wrapper with SWIG or CTypes.

So I guess you could give it a try with Python, but as always there will be a trade off between performance and abstractness.

Comment: thanks dude , i just read few articles stating that extensive scientific libraries are available in python , so i though of working in it 
Reference :http://www.scientificcomputing.com/High-Performance-Development-with-Python.aspx
If not what kind of language shall i use , can you suggest any ?